# node.js issues with Meteor's file system

Tags: node.js, meteor, filereader, file-writing

I have tried to figure out what i am missing from this puzzle between. Node.js and Meteor.js. Meteor is built on Node.js i know this. But Meteor doesn't not work properly with Node.js. Either I need to do 20 more steps to get the same result, which I don't know what they are. Or there is a serious bug between the two. Standalone Node.js runs the command below just fine. Running the same commands on Meteor cause errors or undefined results. Wish i had a why to solve this or they need to patch this so it will work the way it should work.

```
examples #1 

var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});

example #2

var jetpack = require('fs-jetpack');

var data = jetpack.read('file.txt');
console.log(data);

example #3

 var fs = require ('fs');

 var readMe = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
 console.log(readMe);
```

Comment: Meteor runs using Fiber which makes the NodeJS calls synchronous. Meteor also uses DDP.connect to the server. Meteor is the output of the DDP.connect call. Previous versions of Meteor (< Meteor 1.3) used to run npm packages by using Meteor.npmRequire which gives the binding environment for npm packages. For more information of Fibers, please check https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html

Comment: What exaclty is your question? Which error messages do you get?

Comment: When i run the codes on meteror. I either get an :Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' or I get a file undefined. Can't do anything with neither results. You can recreate the problem and see the issue that I have. Not a lot of code involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to load files like this because *you don't know what the folder structure looks like*. Meteor creates builds from your project directory, both in development and production mode. This means that even though you have a `file.txt` in your project folder, it doesn't end up in the same place in the build (or it isn't even included in the build at all).

For example, your code tries to read the file from the development build folder `.meteor/local/build/programs/server`. However, this folder doesn't contain `file.txt`.

**Solution:** Store `file.txt` in the `private` folder of your project and use [`Assets.getText`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-getText) to read it. If you still want to use the functions from `fs` to load the file, you can retrieve the absolute path with [`Assets.absoluteFilePath`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-absoluteFilePath).